# why do i have to keep doing iisreset for my mvc4 app on iis6 to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an mvc4 app working fine on my dev box(windows 7 iis 7)...moved the app to staging(windows server 2003 iis6). After a lot of research found out various options for getting this to work as per
here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

and here:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

The site works well with the wildcard option but after a few hours the guys testing kept complaining that the app took forever to load or doesnt even load at all and gives the message `server application unavailable`. I tried the .aspx option. same issue.

However, after running the command `iisreset` from command prompt.viola the app will load just fine.

Is anyone familiar with this issue or should i just start rewritting the whole app with webforms? because staging and live environment are the same and we cant be "iisresetting" live environment.

Comment: Rewrite the application? If anything, you should move to a newer OS and IIS 7. *On July 14, 2015, all Windows Server 2003 support, including security updates and security-related hotfixes, will be terminated.*

Comment: well i'd have to quote you to management...cos as at today i'm stucked with this option